# not able to pass argument to python file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, sys

I am a beginner in Python and I am trying to pass the argument to the .py file through the command line and using sys.argv to get it, it is not working and showing error. The file name is task-img-reading.py and it only contains two lines of code that is:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

and the error I am getting is:

task-img-reading.py : The term 'task-img-reading.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
task-img-reading.py

```
    CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (task-img-reading.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Suggestion [3,General]: The command task-img-reading.py was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type:
 ".\task-img-reading.py". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

Comment: You seem to try and run your script as a powershell command/script, not as a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the path to the `python.exe` executable is in your `%PATH%` environment variable,

You will need to run your script with

```
C:\Users\Haseeb> python.exe task-img-reading.py
```

Where `C:\Users\Haseeb>` is your terminal prompt.

I'm guessing you are currently running your script as

```
C:\Users\Haseeb> task-img-reading.py
```